# How to read django variable radio button name in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

TOP PS:To summarize my problem I don't put every thing here.

This question is about making a quiz page in django where user answers the questions and get the result.

Okay so I have a dictionary in django views which is soru_cevaplar that includes soru(question) and cevap(answers). Also cevap includes answers for their (Foreign key) question.

I have read many questions like this but couldn't get it. So in my template I have this:

```html
{%for soru, cevap in soru_cevaplar.items%}
   <p>{{soru.soru_soru|safe}}</p>
   {% for c in cevap%}

     <label>
       <input name="{{c.cevap_soru}}" type="radio" value="{{c.cevap_content}}"/><span>{{c.cevap_content|safe}}</span>
      </label>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<input id="test" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" value="End Test"></input>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var cevap = "{{soru_cevaplar}}";
</script>
```

Cevap is string in JS so can't use it like in python dictionary.
My answers are radio buttons and in my jQuery I know I need to do something like this:

```js
$("#test").on("click", function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name='{{c.cevap_soru}}']:checked").val();
    console.log(radioValue);
  });
```

which returns nothing because input name isn't right.

So what I want to do get the all answer values for each question control them in JS file and after user submit the button tell them the results. And the problem is like to pass cevap or sorular_cevap to the JS file (or use the instance attributes in jQuery) and JS file to understand  `$("input[name='{{c.cevap_soru}}']:checked")` code. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Is your `click` function in a separate static .js file? If so the template won't pass the context data to it. You can try adding the function to the script in your template file.

Comment: yes it is in a separate file. I want to do it like that way, and if they are in the same file, it also not working because c.cevap_soru isn’t a global variable.

Comment: That won't work. If you include the script in your template file and provide the correct context data in your jQuery selector, it should work correctly. Without knowing more it is hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the inputs inside a form and then get the answers on submit like this:

```html
<form id="test-form">
  {%for soru, cevap in soru_cevaplar.items%}
    <p>{{soru.soru_soru|safe}}</p>
    {% for c in cevap%}
      <label>
        <input name="{{c.cevap_soru}}" type="radio"
               value="{{c.cevap_content}}"/>
        <span>{{c.cevap_content|safe}}</span>
      </label>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

  <input class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" value="End Test" />
</form>
```

```js
$('#test-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  var $form = $(this);
  var soru_cevap = {};

  // Prevent the default action of the form. The browser-submit.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Fill in object soru_cevap with the checked answers:
  $form.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(index, elem) {
    soru_cevap[elem.name] = elem.value;
  });

  console.log(soru_cevap);
  // Now soru_cevap should be an object like:
  // { question1: 'given answer', question2: 'other answer' }
});
```

Comment: yep this works. And I get the logic. However at function(index, elem) do we need index here as an arg since we never use it ?

Comment: Glad it works :) No, we don't need to use the index, but it will always be the 1st argument (that's how jQuery's `each` works), so we have to declare it.